# How to convert a matrix of torch.tensor to a larger tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch

I meet a problem to convert a python matrix of torch.tensor to a torch.tensor

For example, `M` is an `(n,m)` matrix, with each element `M[i][j]` is a torch.tensor with same size `(p, q, r, ...)`. How to convert python list of list `M` to a torch.tensor with size `(n,m,p,q,r,...)`
e.g.

```
M = []
for i in range(5):
    row = []
    for j in range(10):
        row.append(torch.rand(3,4))
    M.append(row)
```

How to convert above `M` to a torch.tensor with size `(5,10,3,4)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `torch.stack()` to stack a list of tensors on the first dimension.

```py
import torch

M = []
for i in range(5):
    row = []
    for j in range(10):
        row.append(torch.rand(3,4))
    row = torch.stack(row)
    M.append(row)
M = torch.stack(M)

print(M.size())
# torch.Size([5, 10, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```py
ref = np.arange(3*4*5).reshape(3,4,5) # numpy array
values = [ref.copy()+i for i in range(6)] # List of numpy arrays
b = torch.from_numpy(np.array(values)) # torch-array from List of numpy arrays
```

## References

1. [Converting NumPy Array to Torch Tensor](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/tensor_tutorial.html#converting-numpy-array-to-torch-tensor)